# How to set check build option in web site project

Tags: c#, build, visual-studio-2017

Related to : [-checked (C# Compiler Options)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/checked-compiler-option)

I have a web site project and I want to add `-checked` option in build operation. But the problem is I can't find `Check for arithmetic overflow/underflow` in build tab and there is no `Advance` button for advance options in build tab:

[image]

How I can set `-checked` option for web site?

Thanks

Comment: For a Web Site project, Visual Studio tells the following: "This template does not produce a project file and has limited MSBuild support". So I think you're out of luck, unless you extract the business logic into its own project/library.

Answer (score 1):

Web Site projects are special in a way that they don't have project files. For this reason there is a lack of customization available.

You may want to convert your project to a Web Application — this will allow you to tune your build process as you wish. See [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2009/10/29/converting-a-web-site-project-to-a-web-application-project/) article for conversion process details.

Or you could try to play with [`Directory.Build.props`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build), adding `<CheckForOverflowUnderflow>true</CheckForOverflowUnderflow>` property inside.
This file allows you to customize your build for all projects at once, but I'm not pretty sure that it will be accounted by Web Site compilation process.